# Can not send and receive emoji in ionic 3 chat

Tags: ionic3

I have a small concern for displaying emoji in ionic 3.

I created my chat application where I use emoji, but when I send an emoji it sends an empty message to the reception of the latter.

So, how can I send an emoji?
Or, how to convert emoji to unicode plain text?

Thank you guys, I'm waiting for your feedback!

Here are some codes:

**Message.ts**

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { EmojiPickerItem } from './../../model/emoji-picker/emoji-picker.interface';
.......

export class MessagePage {

selectedImojiPickerIten: EmojiPickerItem;
showEmojiPicker = false;
editorMsg = "";


constructor(navParams: NavParams,....){}

    switchEmojiPicker() {
        this.showEmojiPicker = !this.showEmojiPicker;
        if (!this.showEmojiPicker) {
            // this.messageInput.setFocus();
        }
        this.content.resize();
        this.scrollToBottom();
    }

    emoji(event) {
        this.selectedImojiPickerIten = event;
        this.editorMsg += this.selectedImojiPickerIten.emoji
      }
```

**Message.html**

```
<ion-footer [style.height]="showEmojiPicker ? '255px' : '55px'">
    <ion-grid class="input-wrap">
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-2>
                <button ion-button clear icon-only item-right (click)="switchEmojiPicker()">
                    <ion-icon name="md-happy"></ion-icon>
                </button>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-8>
                <ion-textarea #chat_input [(ngModel)]="editorMsg" #chat_input placeholder="Message" (keyup.enter)="sendMsg()" (ionFocus)="onFocus()"
                    (ionChange)="isTyping()">
                </ion-textarea>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-2>
                <button ion-button clear icon-only item-right class="'message-editor-button' + message.ownership" (click)="sendMsg()">
                    <ion-icon name="ios-send" ios="ios-send" md="md-send"></ion-icon>
                </button>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
    <emoji-picker (selectedImojiPickerIten)="emoji($event)" *ngIf="showEmojiPicker" [(ngModel)]="editorMsg"></emoji-picker>
</ion-footer>
```

[Message page when sending an emoticon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psiYa.png)

[Message page after sending and leaving the page, the message becomes blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snnPx.png)

So once the emoji sent in a message, the message left empty without content. I can not send and receive emoji in my Chat App.

Comment: are the emojis you are using _images_? they are represented by unicode by default

Comment: Yes @SurajRao, I have a JSON file where there is unicode emoji, but when sending it goes empty. Even when you send me an emoji message, it happens empty